# Create multiple variables using for loop in lua

Tags: variables, for-loop, lua, iteration, coronasdk

I want to use a for loop to create multiple varibles (with names that are the same except for the last character) in lua

```
for i= 1, 10, 1 do
        marker+i = "do things"
    end
```

pretty much I what I want to get is: marker0, marker1, marker2 and so on. and I guess there is something wrong with marker+i

I get an error. Thank you.

Comment: I think you'd be much better off creating a table: `marker={}`, `marker[i]=...`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to do this actually. Much simpler would be to create a table and create those variables as keys in the table.

```
t={}
for i=1, 10, 1 do
    t["marker"..i] = "do things"
end
```

(Note that `..` is contatenation and not `+` in lua. Note also that you need to quote a string and not use it literally.)

But if you *really* want those to be global variables and not keys in some other table you can generally (depending on environment) do the following

```
for i=1, 10, 1 do
    _G["marker"..i] = "do things"
end
```

Comment: Or simply use `marker` as the table name and index it directly: `marker[i]`.

Comment: @lhf Indeed. I assumed the constructed variable names had a point in themsevles but that may not be the case either.