# use for loop to call multiple functions in lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, coronasdk, lua-table, scene

I want to call multiple methods in lua that are very similar except their parameters change  by one character. The way I'm doing it now works but is extremely in efficient.

```
function scene:createScene(event)

screenGroup = self.view

level1= display.newRoundedRect( 50, 110, 50, 50, 5 )
level1:setFillColor( 100,0,200 )
level2= display.newRoundedRect( 105, 110, 50, 50, 5 )
level2:setFillColor (100,200,0)
--and so on so forth

screenGroup:insert (level1)
screenGroup:insert (level2)
screenGroup:insert (level3)
screenGroup:insert (level4)

end
```

I plan on extending the screenGroop:insert method to hundreds of levels, maybe up to (level300). As you can see the way I'm doing it now is inefficient. I tried doing

```
for i=1, 4, 1 do 
screenGroup:insert(level..i)
end
```

but I get the error "table expected."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create multiple variables using for loop in lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133159/create-multiple-variables-using-for-loop-in-lua)

Answer (score 3):

The best way in this case is to probably use a table:

```
local levels = {}
levels[1] = display.newRoundedRect( 50, 110, 50, 50, 5 )
levels[1]:setFillColor( 100,0,200 )
levels[2] = display.newRoundedRect( 105, 110, 50, 50, 5 )
levels[2]:setFillColor (100,200,0)
--and so on so forth

for _, level in ipairs(levels) do
  screenGroup:insert(level)
end
```

For other alternatives check the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133159/create-multiple-variables-using-for-loop-in-lua) from @EtanReisner's comment.

Answer (score -1):

If your 'level' tables are global, which is appears they are, you can use `getfenv` to index them.

```
for i = 1, number_of_levels do
    screenGroup:insert(getfenv()["level" .. i])
end
```

`getfenv` returns the environment, with all global variables, in the form of a dictionary.  Therefore, you can index it like a normal table like `getfenv()["key"]`